# Cleaning up unused spaces in an array

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If i have an array with a length of 20:

```
int[] arr = new int[20] { 3, 7, 2, 99, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

and I enter only 5 numbers, how do I then remove the 0's from that array?

```
int[] arr = new int[] { 3, 7, 2, 99, 4 };
```

With basic methods, won't use the `Linq` and `Collections.Generics` yet.

Comment: `and I enter only 5 number` just  count numbers user entered

Comment: @L.B how do i do that? when i make the array i don't know how many numbers are going to be entered

Comment: Arrays are inmutable, you could convert it to List<int> then remove the zeroes, then convert it back to array. Anyway, why not use more friendly collections like List?

Comment: Use a `List<int>`. It lets you add or remove elements and re-define its Capacity.

Comment: Use `List<int>` instead of a fixed size `int[]`, then `.Add` the numbers to the list as the user enters them. That way you won't need to remove anything.

Comment: @bradbury9 learning arrays atm, and converting to list is linq

Comment: Well, arrays are inmutable...

Comment: Lists are from collections.generic

Comment: @Bradly **1-** Create a *big enough* array, **2-** Add numbers users entered to that array and count the numbers. **3-**  Copy the original array to a new array (you know at that point the size of the new array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int[] arr = new[] { 3, 7, 2, 99, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

**Removing 0s without Linq or Collections.Generics:**

```
int[] newArr = new int[arr.Length];
int newSize = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    if (arr[i] != 0)
    {
        newArr[newSize] = arr[i];
        newSize++
    }

if (newSize > 0)
    Array.Resize(ref newArr, newSize);
```

If you know how many items the user has entered you could also just do:

```
Array.Resize(ref arr, numberOfItemsUserEntered);
```

or

```
int[] newArr = new int[numberOfItemsUserEntered];

Array.Copy(Array, newArr, numberOfItemsUserEntered);
```

**Removing 0s with Linq (for completeness)**:

```
arr = arr.Where(i => i != 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you, would the same work for Array.Copy, instead of Resize?

Comment: @Bradly i added a `Array.Copy` version to my answer as well. If this helped you solve your question, please mark it as the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Since you cannot use Linq or any of the other collections, you can use `Array.Resize`:

```
Array.Resize(ref arr, newSize);
```

where `newSize` should be replaced with the amount of numbers the user entered, so in your case it would be `5`.

On another note, why declare the array to have 20 elements in the first place? a better solution would be to ask the user how many items they want to enter then you can simply construct an array based on the given input.

This way you don't have to construct an array with a predefined size and later having to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] arr = { 3, 7, 2, 99, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

first locate the first 0 with

```
int index = Array.FindIndex(arr, x => x == 0);
```

then you can call

```
Array.Resize(ref arr, index);
```